# MVC 4 Form submission doesn't result in desired url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a form to allow the user to pick a date and pass it back to the controller by way of url parameters.  My intention is to have the form submit a url that looks like Payroll/Index/id?employeeID="foo"?DayInWeekInput="bar".  Instead this generates the url Payroll/Index/id? so I'm obviously doing something wrong.  How can I do this with a form?  If it's not possible, could you explain an alternative?  Thanks.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Payroll", new { id = @ViewBag.SupervisorID, employeeID=@ViewBag.EmployeeID }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="date" id="DayInWeekInput" value="@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.SpecifiedWeekStart)" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </div>                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you stopped naming,  if you keep the names up it should work for you

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Payroll", new { id = @ViewBag.SupervisorID, EmployeeID = @ViewBag.EmployeeID, DaysInWeekInput = "bar" }, FormMethod.Get))
```

Since that didn't work for you I would try an ajax call next

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action( "Index", "Payroll" )',
        data: { 
            id: @ViewBag.SupervisorID,
            EmployeeID:  @ViewBag.EmployeeID
        },
        success: function (_result) {
            if (_result.Success) {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

I would also recommend putting your id's in hidden fields.  Viewbag can be unstable.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't get it. Looking to set the first two parameters explicitly, and then have the date editor specify the third (DaysInWeekInput).

Comment: I'm pretty new to Asp.Net and web development in general, so bear with me please. I enclosed the javascript with <script> tags and then made the class of the submit button btnSubmit. Is there anything else I need to do to get this to work?  Also, is there a way for me to capture the date value in the date picker and pass it with that ajax function too?

Comment: no problem.  Make sure you have type=text/javascript in your script tag.  make sure you have jquery referenced in your page so that this code will run.  For adding the date picker you just need to add:  Date: $('#DayInWeekInput').val().  Also make sure that the names of the parameters in your controller match the names you are setting in your data

Comment: Ajax doesn't appear to be firing. Above the ajax call you wrote I have <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2js"></script> and then the Ajax call. I've specified the type to be javascript in the tag.  Visual Studio is also reporting syntax errors on the lines in the data section which call ViewBag, and I haven't been able to figure out why. My data section looks like data: { id: ViewBag.SupervisorID, employeeID: ViewBag.EmployeeID, DayInWeekInput: $('#DayInWeekInput').val() },  I went ahead and removed the HTML form and just have a datepicker and a button, with the correct id's or classes.

Comment: I've got an @ before the viewbag calls, just had to remove in since StackOverflow thought I was referencing a poster.

Comment: try putting quotes around the viewbags to see if that helps with syntax.  In your console do you get any errors when the page loads?